# Linux GID and groups

Tags: linux, user-permissions, setgid

On Linux systems, /etc/passwd file contains an UID and a GID per user.
GID represents the ID of the primary group of the user.

But we can also set additional groups to a user with /etc/group file.

Is there a difference between primary and additional groups for a user ?

Let's take 2 examples:

- Example 1:

/etc/passwd:

```
test:x:1000:151:test,,,:/home/test:/bin/bash
```

/etc/group

```
group1:x:151:
group2:x:152:test
group3:x:153:
```

In this example, test is member of group1 (as main group because his gid is 151) and group2.

- Example 2:

/etc/passwd:

```
test:x:1000:152:test,,,:/home/test:/bin/bash
```

/etc/group

```
group1:x:151:test
group2:x:152:
group3:x:153:
```

In this example, test is member of group1 and group2 (as main group because his gid is 152).

Is there a difference in effective user permissions between this 2 examples ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The check is done using the calling process's real UID and GID,
> rather than the effective IDs as is done when actually attempting an
> operation (e.g., open(2)) on the file.  Similarly, for the root user,
> the  check uses the set of permitted capabilities rather than the set
> of effective capabilities; and for non-root users, the check uses an
> empty  set  of capabilities.

> Is there a difference between primary and additional groups for a user

Yes,
If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the  real
user  (group)  id,  and the -p option is not supplied, no startup files are read,
shell functions are not inherited from the environment, the SHELLOPTS,  BASHOPTS,
CDPATH, and GLOBIGNORE variables, if they appear in the environment, are ignored,
and the effective user id is set to the real user id.  If the -p option  is  sup‐
plied  at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id
is not reset.

> Is there a difference in effective user permissions between this 2
> examples ?

Yes,

Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/2/access and https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: supplementary groups is not the same as Effective GID. OP asks about supplementary groups behavior, but your answer appears to be about having a different effective group ID.

Comment: I can understand that you jumped on "*effective user* permissions", but the context is clear enough to understand it didn't mean EUID or EGID.